# Copy large files from Production Openshift/Kubernetes PVC to Non-Prod PVC

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

My requirement is to copy large files from Kubernetes Prod PVC to Non-Prod PVC? This has to happen by a scheduled job. What options do I have to achieve this? Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that please remember that the Prod PVC has to be on filesystem/volume which supports multiple access modes (for example, NFS can support multiple read/write clients).

Filesystems like ext4 are not clustered and you cannot have two different systems accessing the same ext4 filesystem (unless you involve clustered software ...).
This web page https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes shows which k8s volumes can be used with "ReadWriteMany" mode i.e.:

1. NFS
2. CephFS
3. Glusterfs
4. Portworx Volumes

Another option is to have a sidecar container (part of Prod pod) which has access to the Prod PVC (this is supported) and periodically copy the file to the Non-Prod PVC (which also has to be mounted in the pod).